# What does this MOSFET do in this voltage regulation circuit?

Tags: mosfet, voltage-regulator, battery-charging

In the below schematic, V_USB is connected to the +5V of a USB jack, that the user can plug and unplug. There is also a backup LiPo Battery, whose positive terminal is represented by V_BATT. From my point of view, the MOSFET's function here should be to disconnect the battery from the voltage regulator's input when USB is connected. However, it seems to me that when V_USB is +5V, the MOSFET will close the connection, and V_USB will be connected to V_BATT. Shouldn't the MOSFET be closed when V_USB is low, and open when V_USB is high, the opposite of what it is now?

[image: Picture of schematic]

Comment: I'll somewhat disagree. When Vusb is absent the battery powers the regulator with low voltage drop. When Vusb is present the FET is turned off and Vusb powers the regulator via D2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a P-channel MOSFET. But it's in *backwards*, so it's basically acting as a diode due to the body diode. That's ok, as I will explain below.

Assume that the battery is one LiPo cell (3.7 ~ 4.1V max.) With the V_USB off, then the FET body diode is forward biased. The FET is also turned on (fun fact: current can flow in either direction in a FET.)

Now turn on V_USB. D2 conducts and current flows. The FET body diode is no longer forward biased, so no current flows. The FET is also turned off.

Go ahead, [try it here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKACdwAWT8YlLnigSEoyeCwDmAkEJFhuMjPyqQWAd2lg%20mjCNUb5PMLt79jelgBNT4Eyk5VzM8ADkEGZiwBmisyjy%20IHhU2Njg0EgwkCjqMsJBjgrBULGYfgGG4P4pBgpg2ZlOqgBK0snM-MkqIA4g2NDk1TAILKWFBflZAdW1kaLNqbVOoXIm%20nXYctkjCTkTIsn%20AVXs8zYzsqJg4hozWvx7Y5JrmxtK-SyTATPJ2Hg8VXOHInvZqgAeIAzkeEh4EHgAoIeAA1AD6ACEAIIAFRhLE%20DCQYGwPBw4Gw5GBIHBAFUAMoQhE1bAAkScDxBYg1GSggCSLkuAWp1SQ4OhcKZyH61DxhJYQA)

[image]

Now, see what happens when the FET is flipped ([try it](http://assign%20spi_dq_out%20=%20dq_out;%20%20%20%20%20//%20to%20IO%20pad%20assign%20spi_dq_t%20=%20dq_t;)!)

[image]

When the USB_5V is on, the FET body diode conducts... into the battery. Eventually overcharging it and possibly blowing it up! Oops.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know too much about MOSFETs, and didn't realize I was looking at a P-channel MOSFET.

Comment: It's a poor man power source switch but it works :D at first glance I mistook it for a polarity protector but that's done with N channels

Comment: Cool circuit and great answer, directly to the point. I'd like to kindly point out more explicitly that the body diode only conducts during the switchover (between FET turning on/off and the Schottky conducting or not).

Comment: Why could we not just replace the MOSFET with a diode from the battery into the voltage regulator?

Comment: A diode introduces Vf drop. This wastes power, which we care about from the battery more than we care from USB. When V_USB is off, the FET is fully ON and has almost no forward drop, so there's no wasted power. You can edit the sim and try it.